# HTML email sent by Laravel MailGun driver is not displayed property by GMail

Tags: html, email, laravel-5

When using Mailtrap driver in Laravel 5, my HTML email is displayed properly.  But when I switched to use MailGun driver email and check it in Gmail, CSS styling is not working properly.

Here is sample original email displayed by GMail:

```
To: user@gmail.com
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.=
w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns=3D"http://www.=
w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta name=3D"viewport" content=3D"width=
=3Ddevice-width" />
    <meta http-equiv=3D"Content-Type" content=3D"text=
/html; charset=3DUTF-8" />
    <title>iScholar Registration</title>
   =
 <style type=3D"text/css">
        /* -----------------------------------=
--
```

I can see that lines are appended by `=` symbol.

Here is how I send the email:

```
Mail::send(
   'email.activation',
   ['activationCode' => $activation->code, 'email' => $email],
   function ($message) use ($email) {
      $message->from('test@test.com', 'registration');
      $message->to($email);
      $message->subject('Activate your account');
   }
);
```

What is the recommended way to send HTML email using MailGun REST driver in Laravel 5?

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find the solution?

Comment: Yes, I've added an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not related to MailGun at all.  For the template to be displayed properly, CSS must be inlined. I used tools described in https://litmus.com/help/email-clients/gmail-no-head/ to solve this.